# CAPTCHA is not shown on registration form but shown in other forms magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha, ultimo

In my registration form the CAPTCHA doesn't work but in login and forgotten password forms is workin perfect. 
Enable CAPTCHA on frontend - Yes.
Select all forms into "Form" box.
I'm using ultimo theme.
Thank you

Comment: check default theme and see whether its working fine

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html try this

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer you with the little element that you provided us, but i try to help you:

1. Look in your browser console if you have some JS error.
2. Check in your theme settings if you have enabled it in register page.
3. Look in register template if you have well a captcha piece of code in :

   ```
   app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

   app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/customer/form/register.phtml
   ```
4. Check in `register.phtml` **head** if you have well the `js`, `css` external, internal url of this captcha.

Comment: I only found login.phtml file in my theme directory which was copied from base. Should I copy and the register.phtml file ???

Comment: Basically, if you haven't it in your theme, Magento go to get it in base, so even you haven't it in your theme, it should work ! but if you did or you'll do some updates, you should copy it from the base to your theme, So check first the original one from your `package/default`, if you haven't it, copy it from base.